# Why does the right side table inside the div move when left side div is adjusted?

Tags: css, asp.net, html, split

I have a page with one content place holder. I need to display the data as two separate columns for the whole page. I tried that with `div` splitting idea but didn't workout. The code I tried is given below.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="GVKUI.WebForm1" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #header,#footer {
            min-height:40px;
        }
        #main-wrap {
            height: 412px;
            width: 335px;
        }
        #sidebar {
            float:left;
            width:50px;
            height:162px;
        }
        #content-wrap {

            float:right;
            width:50px;
            height: 367px;
            width:117px;
            margin-left: 545px;

        }

    </style>

<div  id="header">
     Header
     <br />
</div>
<div id="main-wrap">
    <div(sidebar) id="sidebar"><br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Sathiya
                </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div(sidebar)>
    <div id="content-wrap">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>Nandhinee</td>
              </tr>
          </table>   
    </div>
</div>
     </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give margin-left to the right column i.e(take out this style  margin-left: 545px from #content-wrap ) as you already floating it right so you don't need any left margin.